# Ruby require error

Tags: ruby, require

I'm trying to call the file from the file `cpu.rb` from `main.rb`:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'cpu.rb'
```

But it does not work. I use Netbeans and Ruby 1.9.2. What's the problem?

Comment: What error message do you receive? How does your code look like? What's the file you want to include? Did you install it through a Ruby gem?

Comment: Is `.rb` required to be in the string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ruby 1.9.2 does not include the current file's directory in `$LOAD_PATH`.

You can try using `require_relative` instead:

```
require_relative 'cpu.rb'
```

Or you can supply the actual path:

```
require './cpu.rb'
```

Or you can add the current file's directory to the load path:

```
$LOAD_PATH.unshift File.dirname(__FILE__)
require 'cpu.rb'
```